# Download multiple file from JSON

Tags: c#, json, gridview, download, uwp

I made aplkasi newsstand displays the "judul", "cover", and "harga" on gridview (data taken from json below)
[image: JSON]

Sample data display on gridview:
[image: Gridview Sample]
[image: Selected Gridview]

gridview when selected, then the download button is clicked it will download all the data residing in the bundle on json above (inside the red circle). But, I have a problem, namely: the data in the bundle that can be downloaded only the latest data, while the previous data is not downloaded..

It's the [Project](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D40E9E24C5BFA2EA!13964&authkey=!AG_vmNVUCcaFrzM&ithint=file%2czip)

How to handle it?

Note:

- [JSON link](http://mhndt.com/newsstand/renungan-harian/callback/allWinItems)
- The appearance of the library using a carousel module of syncfusion
- On page Main Page to display the Custom Dialog I use module of Callisto

Comment: Can not understand what are you mean under "can be downloaded only the latest data, while the previous data is not downloaded". Please explain more clearly

Comment: For example: if there are 3 data in a "bundle" on json, then the data can be downloaded data only third (last), but the first data and the second can not be downloaded. How to handle it?

Comment: can anyone give me the sample for multiple download file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested your sample, I think the problem is with this code in your `StoreAll()` method:

```
if (bundleObj.ValueType == JsonValueType.Array)
{
    JsonArray bundle = bundleObj.GetArray();
    foreach (JsonValue groupValue1 in bundle)
    {
        JsonObject groupObject1 = groupValue1.GetObject();

        bundleName = groupObject1["bundle_file"].GetString();
        pathFile = groupObject1["path_file"].GetString();
    }
}
```

and then:

```
file.BundleName = bundleName;

if (file.Tipe == "0")
{
    file.BundlePath = pathFile + bundleName + ".pdf";
}
else if (file.Tipe == "1")
{
    file.BundlePath = pathFile + bundleName;
}
if (licenseInformation.ProductLicenses[file.SKU].IsActive)
{
    file.Harga = "Purchased";
}
```

I can understand that you want to store the `BundleName` and `BundlePath` info in each item of `GridView` in order to download, but your `BundleName` and `BundlePath` are all string type defined in the `BukuAudio` class:

```
public string BundleName { get; set; }

public string BundlePath { get; set; }
```

So when you walk through the `bundle` group, the latest bundle will cover the previous one, this is why you can only download the latest bundle file.

I think you can change the type of `BundleName` and `BundlePath` for example like this:

```
public List<string> BundleName { get; set; }

public List<string> BundlePath { get; set; }
```

And walk trough the `bundle` group like this:

```
file.BundleName = new List<string>();
file.BundlePath = new List<string>();
if (bundleObj.ValueType == JsonValueType.Array)
{
    JsonArray bundle = bundleObj.GetArray();
    foreach (JsonValue groupValue1 in bundle)
    {
        JsonObject groupObject1 = groupValue1.GetObject();

        bundleName = groupObject1["bundle_file"].GetString();
        pathFile = groupObject1["path_file"].GetString();

        file.BundleName.Add(bundleName);
        file.Tipe = tipe;
        if (file.Tipe == "0")
        {
            file.BundlePath.Add(pathFile + bundleName + ".pdf");
            //file.BundlePath = pathFile + bundleName + ".pdf";
        }
        else if (file.Tipe == "1")
        {
            file.BundlePath.Add(pathFile + bundleName);
            //file.BundlePath = pathFile + bundleName;
        }
    }
}
```

But after doing this, you need also modify the code of your "download" part code and maybe other parts like show download info code in your sample.

Here I won't post the modified code in `ItemView_ItemClick` method and `downloadClicked` method since they are not the key point here, and I modified the `OnNavigatedTo` event in your `LibraryPage` like this to download:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    //GC.Collect();
    BukuAudio dlList = e.Parameter as BukuAudio;
    if (dlList != null)
    {
        //DownloadBuku(dlList.BundlePath);
        //downloadfilename.Text = dlList.BundleName;
        //Uri uri = new Uri(dlList.BundlePath);
        //string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(uri.LocalPath);
        //downloadfilename.Text = String.Format("Unduh '{0}'", filename);
        foreach (var path in dlList.BundlePath)
        {
            DownloadBuku(path);
            int i = 0;
            downloadfilename.Text = dlList.BundleName.ElementAt(i);
            i++;
            Uri uri = new Uri(path);
            string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(uri.LocalPath);
            downloadfilename.Text = String.Format("Unduh '{0}'", filename);
        }
        DownloadProgress.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        downloadfilename.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        statusdownload.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        DownloadProgress.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        downloadfilename.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        statusdownload.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Now you can download every bundles after you click one item.

Comment: in code: file.BundleName = new List<string>();
file.BundlePath = new List<string>(); an error like this picture: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Assf-w0FVKyxch0u6N9U1s4E_LI

How to solve this?

Comment: @Rose, since I can't use `Synfusion` package, I copied your code into my sample, you can find my sample [here](https://github.com/GraceFeng/Download-multiple-file-from-JSON), maybe there are other problems, I didn't test this sample very much. For this problem, you need to cut your `BukuAudio file = new BukuAudio();` in that code block and paste before `file.BundleName = new List<string>(); file.BundlePath = new List<string>();`.

Comment: I have a question, how do I download a file from the first file until the last file in sequence? Because when using such code, the downloaded files are not sequentially (depending on file size). And how to overcome that successively file directly (no delay time)? Because when you use this code, then there is a delay time of several seconds to download the first file with the next file in one bundle)

Comment: @Rose, Downloading is not depending on file size, the files will be download together, so if the file is bigger, it will looks like that this file is downloaded later. To download files in order, you can change the `DownloadBuku` method to a Task and call this using async way `await DownloadBuku(path);`, but tested the demo, you should also change the code of displaying download information. And I think I've solved your problem in this question, if you have other questions, please open a new thread.

Answer (score 1):

That's all depend of how do you parse data in JSON and bind it to GridView.
As I suppose you should have some class with subclass inside like:

```
    public class BundleGroup : ObservableCollection<BundleData>
{
    public BundleGroup(IEnumerable<BundleData> items) : base(items)
    {
    }

    public string idfile { get; set; }
    public string judul { get; set; }
    //  etc.
}
```

In this case, after "download" clicking you will be able to loop thrue collection of items in BundleGroup and download all of them.

Comment: For the code above, is made in a new class or in the LibraryPage?

Comment: If you have some class for parsing JSON data, and bind data later to GridView you can have some group inside this class like I have propose. I don't know how do you parse json, but usualy it's possible to do this way